# execute "sp_MSforeachtable" (SQL Server 2008 R2) from Excel 2003 using ADO

Tags: excel, vba, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ado

I want to analyse my DB and get the results for each table into an MS Excel worksheet by executing `"sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];';"` from an ADODB Command or Recordset and then use CopyFromRecordset to output the results into Excel.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub analyseHermesDB()
Dim oConn As Object, oRec As Object, oField As Object, iIndx As Integer

' sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];';
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

oConn.Open "FILE NAME=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\conn.udl"
    With oRec
        .activeconnection = oConn
        .Source = "sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];';"
        .cursorlocation = 3
        .Open
        For iIndx = 0 To .fields.Count - 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, iIndx).Value = .fields(iIndx).Name
        Next
        Do Until .EOF
            ActiveCell.Offset(.absoluteposition, 0).CopyFromRecordset oRec
            .movenext
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = .RecordCount
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is this: When I execute `"sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];';"` in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio I get one resultset for each table.

I am only getting one recordset back from the call using ADO

What am I doing wrong? Should I be trying to get an array of recordsets, or execute `sp_MSforeachtable` to get the list of tables then execute `EXECUTE sp_spaceused [?];'` for each one?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263540(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sp_MSforeachtable returns multiple result sets and you need to consume them this way

However, you can achieve what you want with some simple SQL instead
sp_spaceused uses similar SQL internally anyway...

Feel free to tweak, this is an exact copy/paste of a script I use

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    SUM(ps.reserved_page_count)/128.0 AS ReservedMB, 
    SUM(ps.used_page_count)/128.0 AS UsedMB
FROM
    sys.objects o
    JOIN
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps ON o.object_id = ps.object_id
WHERE
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX(o.object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
GROUP BY
    o.name
ORDER BY
    SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) DESC
```

Comment: +1 that's brilliant, thanks - once again you show mastery of SQL Server's internal workings that goes way beyond what I have reached in 10 years of pretending to be a developer !

Answer (score 1):

> I am only getting one recordset back from the call using ADO

That's not true, you're only evaluating one recordset. Use `NextRecordset` to get the next recordset.

From [Visual Basic Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263540(v=vs.60).aspx):

> Running a Stored Procedure That Returns Multiple Resultsets

```
Private Sub MultipleRSButton_Click()
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   sql = "Select * from Authors Where year_born is not null; " _
    & "Select * from Authors where year_born is  null"
   rs.Open sql, cn
   Do
      i = MsgBox("Ready for results?", vbYesNoCancel)
      If i = vbYes Then
         ADOGrid1.ShowData rs
         Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
      End If
   Loop Until rs.State = adStateClosed
End Sub
```

Note `Set rs = rs.NextRecordset`.

But for all intents and purposes, [gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16586460/242520) is probably better; it doesn't rely on an undocumented stored procedure.

Comment: +1 for answering my question, but [gbn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586348/execute-sp-msforeachtable-sql-server-2008-r2-from-excel-2003-using-ado/16586460#16586460) is better as you say. Thanks